# ZF2 2 modules each one with router hostname

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to setup an app with 2 subdomains, each one with a hostname route and child routes but with no luck.

Any idea / example?

Thanks

Comment: Modules in ZF2 are not "subpaths" to your application. Also, check the HTTP Hostname route: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-hostname

Comment: just to clarify, you want to use two separate subdomains, and have them both handled by separate modules?

Comment: yes Andrew, like public and private, each one with their controllers, layouts, templates and routes

Answer (score 3):

You can use a specific router type named "Hostname" (class "Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Hostname").
Here is a simple example :

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'example1' => array(
            'type' => 'Hostname',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => ':subdomain.mydomain.com',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'subdomain' => 'mysubdomain1',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'MyModule1\Controller\MyFirstController',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'example2' => array(
            'type' => 'Hostname',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => ':subdomain.mydomain.com',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'subdomain' => 'mysubdomain2',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'MyModule2\Controller\MySecondController',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

I would probably split this configuration into two parts, with "example1" in the configuration of my first module and "example2" in the configuration of my second module.

You will find a complete information about that router type and others on [this page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html).

Comment: yay! that's whatI've guessed after looking at source code of ZF2

Comment: Hi, I'm new to ZF2 and have a public and a private hostname, like in the example. I have an Application module and a Private module. But where do I put, in which file, the code above? thx